# Can't open the Asset in IMB Watson Studio

Tags: assets, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I added a .ipynb file in Asset Section of Projects of IBM Watson Studio, but when I try to open the file a pop up displays:

"Preview not available

This file type may not be supported."

I don't know how to fix this and I don't know how to proceed to submit my assignament for Coursera IBM Data Science course.

Please, help

Answer (score 0):

The .ipynb file is for Jupyter notebook. Assuming you are trying to create new notebook to execute some code from that notebook file.

You need to use Add to Project -> Notebook option
[image]

Then use "from file" option to upload
[image]

For more information, refer to the documentation:- https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs?context=cpdaas

Comment: Thank you so so much!

IBM Watson Studio is a bit cumbersome at first :)